# HTTP/2 is here. How can native Android apps take advantage of it?

Tags: android, native, http2

Browsers already [adopted HTTP/2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) and major web servers should all support it within 2015. If client browsers needed adapting to take advantage of HTTP/2, so should client native mobile apps.

How can native Android apps take advantage of HTTP/2 to better communicate with their servers, and what should we be doing (or stop doing) to adapt our native apps, from the front-end point of view?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood correctly your question, but you can use one of the libraries for communicate with servers sharing same connection.

One of the libraries which supports HTTP/2 is [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

But can you provide more details about what do you mean by

> How can native Android apps take advantage of HTTP/2 to better communicate with their servers, and what should we be doing (or stop doing) to adapt our native apps, from the front-end point of view?